# Spring Security and Static web project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My Spring Web project with Spring Security works successfully. I want to separate "view" of the project by creating a new static web project. It will have a login screen, access to pages by user's role etc.

my spring-security.xml file

`<http auto-config="true"> 
   <intercept-url pattern=“/restricted” access="ROLE_ADMIN" /> 
   <form-login login-page="/login"  default-target-url="/welcome"  authentication-failure-url=“/fail” /> 
   <logout logout-success-url="/login" /> 
</http>`

In addition to this, i have REST controllers that return JSON data; but they are stricted if user's role is not ROLE_ADMIN (.../restricted/getlist)

What do i have to do in static web page (client) side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring security tags :

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

Comment: Thank you for your response Jumper. Your answer is for JSP pages. I am looking for static html web pages. Any other recommendation?